How to create a separate subscription reocrds per item in cart in woocommerce
I am working in woocommerce subscription feature, I have a requirement to create a separate subscription record for each item in cart.
Current behaviour: It is creating singel subscription record for multiple item which _subscription_length has same value (basically group item by that field)
I want to create separate subscription for each item everytime. I tried many hook but without luck.
I tried following code but it is creating separate subscription records but along with that it is also creating combined subscription record and in separate record the order data and id is not getting link.
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'create_individual_subscriptions', 20, 2);

function create_individual_subscriptions($order_id, $posted_data) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ($items as $item_id => $item) {
        $product = $item->get_product();

        // Check if the product is a subscription type
        if ($product && ($product->is_type('subscription') || $product->is_type('variable-subscription') || $product->is_type('subscription_variation'))) {
            $access_from = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), 'access_from', true);
            $access_end = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), 'access_end', true);

            if (!$access_from || !$access_end) {
                continue;  // Skip if dates are not properly set
            }

            $start_date = new DateTime($access_from);
            $end_date = new DateTime($access_end);

            // Create a new subscription
            $new_subscription = wcs_create_subscription(array(
                'start_date' => $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'customer_id' => $order->get_customer_id(),
                'billing_period' => $product->get_meta('_subscription_period'),
                'billing_interval' => $product->get_meta('_subscription_period_interval'),
                'parent_id' => $order_id,
            ));

            // Add product to the subscription
            $new_subscription->add_product($product, $item->get_quantity());

            // Set the specific dates for the subscription
            $new_subscription->update_meta_data('_schedule_start', $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $new_subscription->update_meta_data('_schedule_trial_end', $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $new_subscription->update_meta_data('_schedule_next_payment', $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $new_subscription->update_meta_data('_schedule_end', $end_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            $new_subscription->calculate_totals();
            $new_subscription->save();

            // Optionally handle payment and status setup here
            // e.g., $new_subscription->payment_complete();
            // e.g., $new_subscription->update_status('active');
        }
    }
}

